# Configure JWT token expire time when JdbcStore is used

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement Spring Security with OAuth2 using JWT with jdbcTokenStore:

```
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(60);
        defaultTokenServices.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(80);
        defaultTokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(false);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
```

[Github](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt.java#L88)

But after I create Token using Postman I get always value:

```
{
    "access_token": "....",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "....",
    "expires_in": 41502,
    "scope": "read",
    "organization": "admin Drivelog",
    "jti": "2f33707a-30e3-4145-9d9d-7c2e4a4535dd"
}
```

Do ypi know how to configure Access token expire time. For some reason `setAccessTokenValiditySeconds` is not working.

Comment: Check database table `oauth_client_details` column values `access_token_validity` & `refresh_token_validity`

Comment: I created this table but for some reason it's always empty

Comment: Your implementation looks good. Can you share screenshot of postman request ?

Comment: @PeterPenzov if oauth_client_details is empty, where are you storing the client_id's & secrets, etc? The columns that Thirumal mentioned allow you to configure on a per user basis.

Comment: See the description here that I made for another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956660/duplicate-entry-for-key-primary-oauth-token

Comment: You need to include the content in `oauth_client_details` by yourself. That table is used to specify which clients have access to your Oauth server, for that reason, you have to use the information included in `client_id` and `client_secret` columns with Basic authentication to invoke the "security endpoints". You can see an example of them in: https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices#security-services when I talk about `security-oauth-service` microservice

Comment: @doctore I have a question about your project. I saw that you create here https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/security-oauth-service/src/main/java/com/security/oauth/configuration/security/jwt/JwtConfiguration.java#L38 jwtTokenStore, not jdbcTokenStore. This is just to store the certificate used to sign the JWT token or? And second question when I revoke a token is this going to remove from jdbcTokenStore the token? In general the topic for jdbcTokenStore is not very clear how it's working for OAuth2.

Comment: One of the advantage of JWT tokens is that contain the required information to know if the current one was "generated by you" and you can include them what you need to securize your application. That is the reason I prefer don't store them to avoid extra accesses to database (taking into account your security functionality will be used frecuently, it's important don't convert it in a bottelneck). In `security-oauth-service` I only use `oauth_client_details` to know haw to generate access/refresh token and, even in this case, I use a cache to avoid get every time that information from database.

Comment: Due to is was quite complex to find how to include customizations in the current `Spring + Oauth 2.0` integration, I developed `security-jwt-service` which provide a suitable way to allow every application how to generate its own tokens, work with JWE etc. At that point, I prefered to use a distributed cache to deal with the situation `revoke a token` but with a different approach, I mean, "you are not revoking a Jwt token you are included a user into a blacklist".

Comment: In my project, `pizza-service` uses `security-jwt-service` to securize their endpoints but the first one does not know that Jwt token is used for that (it allows to me, if necessary, change it in the future without modify `pizza-service`). On the other hand, only `pizza-service` knows how to deal with their users, for that reason, it is on this microservices on which I included the "blacklist of users" to manage the situation: revoke Jwt token (really do not allow a user uses my application).

Comment: To see how to add/remove users to the blacklist: https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/pizza-service/src/main/java/com/pizza/controller/UserController.java. To see how to manage the situation "this user cannot use my application" (through the Jwt token): https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/pizza-service/src/main/java/com/pizza/configuration/security/SecurityManager.java

At this point, you can use a similar approach in only one application, keep storing the tokens in database, etc You need to consider the your requirements to take a decision.

Comment: ok, let's start from the requirements. I need to create authentication mechanism for Spring application + Angular. It's important to: 1. Share the session between many servers in order to have high availability and to have non interruption when some server is down. 2. When user is not active more than 10 min to redirect him automatically to login page(to expire the user session). I think that the solution with `JwtTokenStore` is a  good alternative to `jdbcTokenStore` but I don't know can it be used between several servers. Maybe with NFS share? Have you tried this between several servers?

Comment: If you ask a new question with your requirements and the alternatives you have tested, you will receive the help of several persons. Answering your questions briefly: **1.** Jwt tokens will help you for that, every request in Angular will send it in the header so, any available server will receive it and manage in a suitable way. **2.** Jwt tokens works in the "other side", that is, every one (access or refresh) should include an `expiration time` value, so you can specify this user can make requests during 10 minutes, but the concept is "the same" you are looking for.

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtTokenStore.html to know the difference.
`I don't know can it be used between several servers... Have you tried this between several servers?` why do you need it? To manage the security functionality is not required, because that one will be send by your Angular application and manage by any available server. To manage the "revoke token" situation, I used another approach: a distributed cache (in my case Hazelcast), but you can store them in database as easier alternative.

Comment: In my case I want to have servers in USA and Europe as independent sites. When I switch web users to use site B I need to make the sessions available using database  session cache. It's important to replicate the sessions between many servers into several sites because users will be forced to login again.

Answer (score -1):

You may have forgotten to configure your resourceserver to use the tokenservices, for example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

@Autowired
private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**","/oauth/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/jwttest/**" ).authenticated();
}
}
```

as found in https://medium.com/@dassum/securing-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-and-jdbc-token-store-67558a7d6c29